# Query error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

I got error like this

ERROR - 2021-02-09 20:01:03 --> Query error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 - Invalid query: select fdr_id as id, fdr_name ,fdr_parent as parent_id,fdr_type, fdr_lvl,fdr_hierarcy,fdr_drive, fdr_ukeydate as tanggal FROM acs_adm_folder WHERE fdr_flag <> 'D' and fdr_id=

this is my sql inside my php file

```
public function get_fdrproperty($id) {
    $sql = "
    select fdr_id as id
         , fdr_name 
         , fdr_parent as parent_id
         , fdr_type
         , fdr_lvl
         , fdr_hierarcy
         , fdr_drive
         , ";
    $sql .="fdr_ukeydate as tanggal 
      FROM acs_adm_folder 
     WHERE fdr_flag <> 'D' 
       and fdr_id=". $id  ;
```

Can you help me find what mistake i made?

Comment: The variable `$id` is most likely null or an empty string but the SQL expects it to be an unquoted integer causing the query to end with `and fdr_id=`. Use a query parameter instead of concatenating a variable to ensure it is passed as a real value.

Comment: can you give example? i just learning and i dont really understand what is query paramater

Comment: You tagged this with `codeigniter` - you should use a query binding as described in https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#query-bindings - `and fdr_id = ?` and pass `$id` in bind param

Comment: At a minimum with the code you are using now, if you used `intval($id)` it would at least cast a null id to zero, which would cause presumably no rows to return but the query would be syntactically valid and injection safe.

Comment: i tried this option from you codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#query-bindings. But its generate new error
Severity: Warning --> Undefined variable $db

Comment: That assumes the codeigniter database connection was `$db`. Your code probably has a different variable which you have not posted here. If you need additional help with the PHP, you will need to update your question to included the PHP code which calls your function `get_fdrproperty()`